# Is it possible to get data from shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

what am trying to do is getting the `Position` of the vertex after translation, rotation, scaling, and get the `Normal` direction, after translation, rotation, scaling , then pass the values to my C++ app , is that possible ?

Comment: write it to texture and then get the texture data in C++ app (you will need encode your data to match texture format) and also you are limited in number of vertexes by used texture size. Also may be you will need to add index of point to your mesh data so shader knows where to write inside texture...

Answer (score 2):

Possible yes, but the most elegant method depends on the OpenGL version profile available. The most elegant solution would be vertex transform feedback https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback

If you don't have VTF you'll have to write the information into the framebuffer (in a fragment buffer object) for readback (this will of course prevent you from seeing a "image" but just give you color coded information). Render in GL_POINTS mode, use the `gl_VertexID` to set the fragment position, pass the transformed data to the fragment shader and have the fragment shader write it into the right color channels.